# posting php variable that contains apostrophe

Tags: php, post, escaping, apostrophe

I am having trouble posting a php variable to another page. The variable is retrieved from a dropdown selected by the user and if it contains an apostrophe, I only get the part prior to the apostrophe posted.  I.E. If I want to post "Cooper's Hawk" I am only receiving "Cooper".  How do I escape this properly so that I can post the entire string?

This is what I have:

```
 echo '<form method="POST" action="advanced_search2.php">';
 $dropdown_english_name = "<select class = 'dropdown' name='english_name'>     <option>ALL</option>";


$query = "SELECT DISTINCT english_name FROM moth_sightings WHERE user_id ='$username'ORDER BY english_name asc";
                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "<tr><td>English Name:</td>";
                while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
                    {
                       $dropdown_english_name .= "\r\n<option class = 'dropdown_active' value='{$row['english_name']}'>{$row['english_name']}</option>";
                    }
                $dropdown_english_name .= '\r\n</select>';
                echo '<td>' .  $dropdown_english_name .'</td></tr>';
```

on different page

```
$posted_value = ($_POST['english_name']);
 echo $posted_value;die;
```

So, to clarify from the above code, the posted string is "cooper's hawk" but the echoed output is "Cooper".
Thanks in advance for any tips.

Comment: Most likely you're using single quotes to wrap the options' value attribute and not escaping them before echoing those in the php.

Comment: There's no "Cooper's Hawk" option in the select box. SHow us how this is generated.

Comment: ` echo;$posted_value;die;` isn't exactly valid syntax...

Comment: Ok, I have added the details of option so you can see how it is generated.  @Mark B, the echo; was an error in my post but in the original code.  Thanks for spotting.

Answer (score 3):

You've probably broken you form by generating it as

```
 <select ...><option value='cooper's hawk'>...</option></select>
                                  ^---
```

with that construct, you get a submitted value of `cooper`, and the option tag ends up with two unknown attributes `s` and `hawk`. Be careful when building html forms like that. You **HAVE** to make sure that embedded quotes in your data don't fundamentally alter the structure of the html, e.g. use mixed quotes, or encoded quotes:

```
values="cooper's hawk"
values="cooper&#39;s hawk"
```

would both work. note the different quoting styles.

Comment: To be safe, always use [htmlspecialchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape special characters.

Comment: I think this might be the problem, but I am not sure about how to repair it. Any hints. Note I have now included the source fo the option value in the code above.

Comment: @user1658170: you got your hint: use htmlspecialchars to escape the special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You could use php function `addslashes($variable)`